How to use libuv multithreading correctly on Windows？
create a thread
if (uv_thread_create(&tun_pf.thread_id, on_receive_packet, NULL) != 0) {
    log_error("uv thread create failed");
    return false;
}

function on_receive_packet:
static void on_receive_packet(void* arg) {
    (void)arg;
    while (tun_pf.running) {
        DWORD PacketSize;
        BYTE* Packet = WintunReceivePacket(tun_pf.session, &PacketSize);
        if (Packet)
        {
            log_debug("tun read %ld bytes, id: %lld ", PacketSize, GetCurrentThreadId());
            if (PacketSize < sizeof(struct ip)) {
                WintunReleaseReceivePacket(tun_pf.session, Packet);
                return;
            }
            work_task_t* work_task = (work_task_t*)calloc(1, sizeof(work_task_t));
            if (work_task) {
                work_task->buf = uv_buf_init(Packet, PacketSize);
                uv_req_set_data(&work_task->req, work_task);
                uv_queue_work(client_main.loop, &work_task->req, on_worker_func, on_after_worker_func);
            }
            else {
                WintunReleaseReceivePacket(tun_pf.session, Packet);
            }
        }
    }
}


There is no problem with receiving packages, function on_worker_func and on_after_worker_func:
static void on_worker_func(uv_work_t* req) {
    // empty
}

static void on_after_worker_func(uv_work_t* req, int status) {
    work_task_t* work_task = (work_task_t*)uv_req_get_data(req);
    if (work_task) {
        log_debug("tun worker %ld bytes, thread id: %lld ", work_task->buf.len, GetCurrentThreadId());
        uint8_t buffer[X_TUN_BUFF_SIZE] = { 0 };
        uint8_t* packet = buffer + X_TUN_PACKET_HEAD_ROM;
        uint16_t packet_len = X_TUN_PACKET_BUF_SIZE;
        if (work_task->buf.len < packet_len) {
            memcpy(packet, work_task->buf.base, work_task->buf.len);
            if (tun_pf.on_read_fn) {
                tun_pf.on_read_fn(packet, (uint32_t)work_task->buf.len);
            }
        }
    }
    // The content above should have been in on_after_worker_func, but there is a problem placing it there...
    if (work_task) {
        WintunReleaseReceivePacket(tun_pf.session, (BYTE*)work_task->buf.base);
    }
    free(work_task);
}

In main thread:
uv_run(cmp->loop, UV_RUN_DEFAULT);

If you need more information, I would be happy to.
My problem is that after running normally for a period of time, the program will crash due to assertions(Assertion failed: uv__has_active_reqs(req->loop),file D:project\lib\libuv\src\threadpool.c, line 359).
To debug, I added some printing:
#define uv__has_active_reqs(loop)                                             \
    (loop)->active_reqs.count > 0 ? 1 : (printf("uv__has_active_reqs:%lld ", GetCurrentThreadId()) && 0)

#define uv__req_register(loop, req)                                           \
  do {                                                                        \
    (loop)->active_reqs.count++;                                              \
    printf("register a req:%lld\n",GetCurrentThreadId());                    \
  }                                                                           \
  while (0)

#define uv__req_unregister(loop, req)                                         \
  do {                                                                        \
    assert(uv__has_active_reqs(loop));                                        \
    printf("unregister a req:%lld\n",GetCurrentThreadId());                  \
    (loop)->active_reqs.count--;                                              \
  }                                                                           \
  while (0)

Here a log:
register a req:36124
unregister a req:36124
unregister a req:36124
unregister a req:36124
register a req:36124
unregister a req:36124
register a req:36124
unregister a req:36124
register a req:27776
register a req:36124
unregister a req:36124
register a req:27776
register a req:36124
unregister a req:36124
unregister a req:36124
unregister a req:36124
unregister a req:36124
register a req:27776
unregister a req:36124
register a req:36124
unregister a req:36124
register a req:36124
unregister a req:36124
unregister a req:36124
uv__has_active_reqs:36124 Assertion failed: uv__has_active_reqs(req->loop),

I don't know if using libuv in this way is correct, maybe it's a platform issue?
